# songs package: how to store gtab definitions in an external file?

Tags: songs

I'm using the [Songs](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) latex package.
I'm currently defining the guitar fret diagrams of a chord for each song, but I'd like to define them in an external file to include them in each song (in order to not repeat myself).

How can I do this?

The diagrams and the command \gtab are explained here:
http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#sec6

but I couldn't find any useful info.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Saving that code in a file `diagram.tex` and then use `\input{diagram.tex}` in your books can be an option?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to be able to specify different definitions inside theexternnal file, while  \input just copies the whole content of the file.

Comment: How would you decide what definitions to use?  Is it feasable to create a lot of diagram.tex-files and include them as needed?

Comment: I don't like this solution. How can I define a variable in Latex?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to create a "database" of tabs diagrams.

You could create a database with two columns, the first for the names of the chords and the second for the tab description (they will become the first and the second arguments of `\gtab` command).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tabs.txt}
A,X02220:001230
C#sus4,4:XX3341
B&,X13331
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{songs}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g_fedelibre_get_tabs_ior
\prop_new:N \g_fedelibre_tabs_prop

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fedelibre_add_to_prop:w #1,#2!!
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_fedelibre_tabs_prop {#1} {#2}
 }
\ior_open:Nn \g_fedelibre_get_tabs_ior {tabs.txt} 
\ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_fedelibre_get_tabs_ior
 {
  \fedelibre_add_to_prop:w #1!!
 } 
\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \fedetab }{ v }
 {
  \prop_get:NnNTF \g_fedelibre_tabs_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \fedelibre_gtab:nV {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \msg_term:n {Maybe~ you~ have~ mispelled~ your~ tab!}
   }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \fedelibre_gtab:nn \gtab
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fedelibre_gtab:nn { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Song}
\beginverse
\fedetab{A}  \fedetab{C#sus4} \fedetab{B&}
 \[C]  \[D]  \[C] 
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

This code reads your databased and stores your entries in a property list. With the `\fedetab{something}` command you print the tab for the `something` chord. If that chord name does not exist, you receive a message.

Thanks to **@egreg** for having solved an expansion problem that made the code useless.